# how to overwrite css height set by jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I have this:

```
 var setHeight = $(this).outerHeight(); 
 // returns e.g. 687

 $("#someElement").css({'height': $setHeight+"px !important" });
 // I want to override this jquery-set height
```

I'm not sure this is the right way... probably not, since it's not working.

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setHeight`, not `$setHeight`. and the `!important` is unneeded.

Answer (score 26):

Your variable name doesn't have a leading `$`. Also, the `!important` flag will cause this not to work in Firefox, however as you're applying this style directly to the element, you shouldn't need it.

```
$("#someElement").css('height', setHeight + "px");
```

Also note that if you're only setting the element's height you can also just shorten this to a `height()` call:

```
$("#someElement").height(setHeight);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variables don't match; remember that punctuation and proper spelling are important to calling the variable properly; try changing the second line to:

```
$("#someElement").css('height',setHeight+'px !important');
```

Answer (score 1):

Take out dollar sign ;) 'setHeight'

Answer (score 0):

That should totally work except that your variable is `setHeight` and you are trying to use `$setHeight`. Make sure they are the same. Make sure your selector is correct and obtaining the element. I believe that you don't even need the `!important`. The style tag should overwrite any .css definition unless you have `!important` in it.