# aria-hidden=true makes height div

Tags: jquery, hidden, wai-aria

I have a slideshow that gives 2 elements that are shown a [aria-hidden=true]. I need the container to scale with the 2 elements that have [aria-hidden=true].

Does anyone know how to script that in Jquery?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking here.  If possible, please provide some sample code.

However, maybe something like this would work:

```
$('[aria-hidden="true"]')
    .parent()
    .css({
        height: '100%'
});
```

Otherwise, here are a few stackoverflow articles that might point you in the right direction:

> [jQuery: Get height of hidden element in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345784/jquery-get-height-of-hidden-element-in-jquery)
>
> [Using jQuery to adjust a parent element's height to match it's
>   visible child's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6882019/using-jquery-to-adjust-a-parent-elements-height-to-match-its-visible-childs-h)
>
> [how to overwrite css height set by jquery/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109406/how-to-overwrite-css-height-set-by-jquery-javascript)

Hope this helps.